# How do I mock an object being returned from a parent object all on the same call

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

so this is my line of code in my concrete method:

```
var patron = patronService.GetPatron(new GetPatronRequest() { PatronId = request.PatronId }).Patron;
```

where my `GetPatron` method returns a `GetPatronResponse` object that has a `Patron` object declared on it.

This is my `TestMethod` so far:

```
[TestMethod]
public void WhenGetPatronPropertyPricingIsCalled_ThenGetPatronPropertyPricingResponseIsReturned()
{
    // Given
    var request = new GetPatronPropertyPricingRequest
    {
         PatronId = "1",
         ServiceCodes = new List<string> { "1" }
    };

    var repo = new Mock<IPatronPropertyPricingServiceRepository>();
    var patronService = new Mock<IPatronsService>();
    var patronPropertyPrice = new PatronPropertyPrice() { CurrencySymbol = "£", ServiceCode = "1", MinimumPrice = 5.00m, MaximumPrice = 10.00m };
    var patronResponse = new GetPatronResponse(new GetPatronRequest());
    var patronRequest = new GetPatronRequest(){ PatronId = "1"};
   // patronService.Setup(x => x.GetPatron(It.IsAny<GetPatronRequest>()).Patron).Returns(patronResponse.Patron);

    patronService.Setup(x => x.GetPatron(It.IsAny<GetPatronRequest>()).Patron).Returns(It.IsAny<Patron>());
    // patronService.Object.GetPatron(new GetPatronRequest() {PatronId = request.PatronId});
    // patronPropertyPrice.Setup(tt => new PatronPropertyPrice() { CurrencySymbol = "£", ServiceCode = "1", MinimumPrice = 5.00m, MaximumPrice = 10.00m });
    repo.Setup(repository => repository.GetPropertyPricing(request.PatronId)).Returns(patronPropertyPrice);

    var svc = new PersistingPatronPropertyPricingService(repo.Object,patronService.Object);

    // When
    var response = svc.GetPropertyPricing(request);

    // Then
    Assert.AreEqual(patronPropertyPrice, response.PatronPropertyPrices);
}
```

What ever I try in the concrete method it always either returns an object not set error or an invalid setup on a non-virtual error at the point I'm trying to set response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume `GetPatron` returns something like a `PatronResponse` with a `Patron` property.

In that case change

```
patronService.Setup(x => x.GetPatron(It.IsAny<GetPatronRequest>()).Patron).Returns(It.IsAny<Patron>());
```

to

```
var patronResponse = new PatronResponse { Patron = new Patron() };
patronService
    .Setup(x => x.GetPatron(It.IsAny<GetPatronRequest>()))
    .Returns(patronResponse);
```

`It.IsAny<T>()` is meant to be used in the setup expression and not as a variable.

Comment: I needed to adapt this, but this definitely got me to where I needed to be. My test is now working. Thank you.